Button behavior condition
I have a Submit button that once pressed run onSubmit function.
<b-form @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit(onSubmit)">
...
    <b-button
        type="submit"
    >Submit</b-button>

<script lang="ts">
private async onSubmit() {
...
}

I want to add a layer before this.
If condition is met, display a modal/message else continue with submit.
The closest I could find what I needed was
onclick="return confirm('message')"

but I couldn't get it to display a modal or pass in a variable.
I am considering adding another Submit button that display the modal @click, but it's not clean.
<b-button
    v-if=conditions
    @click=showmodal
>Submit</b-button>

<b-button v-else
    type="submit"
>Submit</b-button>

<b-modal @ok=submit

Another problem with trying to use onclick is this error. Variable, function, etc.
ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (edit:1:16)

another idea is to parse the condition within onSubit() and display the modal. However, I don't know how to pause the code and wait for a confirmation from the user before continuing.
private onSubit(){
    if condition
       this.$bvModal.show("modal");
    
    ....
}


Finely designed modal api should have been based on promises like if (condition) let isConfirmed = await showModal() in onSubmit. But $bvModal.show is low-level and not  designed this way. This is the motivation for creating your own implementation that wraps around it. Also msgbox does this in case it suits you, https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#modal-message-boxes . Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60547547/3731501

Thank you. I could definitely use this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm

solved with this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm()
bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#modal-message-boxes
